# Struts to spring migration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts

I need to handle this Struts code `String navigatedFrom =  mapping.getParameter();` in Spring code

```
public class foo extends abcAction {
    private static final String TAKEA = "HAi";
        private static final String OTHERO = "otherOptions"; 
        private static final String TAKINGA = "taking";

    @RequestMapping()
    public ModelAndView processDefault(
         ModelMap model,  HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,SystemException {
            String navigatedFrom =  mapping.getParameter();
            //some condtions
    }
}
```

How can I handle `mapping.get` parameter in spring `mapping.getparameter()`?

Comment: There is no ActionMapping in Spring. It's a different framework. Learn how to use it. You can't expect to find a direct 1-to_1 translation of Struts concepts in Spring.

Comment: yes ,but i want know how to handle the strutscode: string navigatedForm = mapping.getParamenter(); in spring code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping is created while processing Struts request. You have nothing to do in Spring rather than providing your own `@RequestMapping`.

If you need to learn more about how to provide mapping to the request in Spring you can read [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

> ```
> @Controller
> public class GreetingController {
>
>     @RequestMapping("/greeting")
>     public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
>         model.addAttribute("name", name);
>         return "greeting";
>     }
> ```

This code clearly shows you how to use attributes in request mapping.